# Compiling Vaadin Widgetsets and Using Generated Files In Another Project

Tags: vaadin

I compiled the GoogleMapWidget (http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/36) using Eclipse, and it generated some files under WEB-INF/vaadin/widgetsets. Then I copied that entire widgetsets directory to another projects in the WEB-INF/vaadin, and tried to use that widget in the second project, but it doesn't seem to want to work.

Are the compiled widgetsets not reusable?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you compile vaadin widget?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried, but I guess it should work. However I don't see any reason that justifies the effort. Widgetset compilation takes about one minute, so why bother.

The widgetset is not meant to be compiled every time you build the application. Only if you do client side widget development or add a new addon that requires wigetset recompilation.

Remember to change the widgetset in your web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <description>Application widgetset</description>
    <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.widgetset.MySharedWidgetset</param-value>
</init-param>
```

You might also want to copy the Widgetset .gwt.xml file to the package you described in your web.xml for param widgetset.